# How multiple quantifiers in a sentence are interpreted

Tags: determiners, logic, quantifiers

> Someone sleeps everyday.

Does this mean that there is someone who sleeps everyday or that everyday someone sleeps?

Comment: Aside from being a silly sentence, it's an ambiguous one, a classic Quantifier Ambiguity, an adverbial version of _Some boy read every book_, which is **either** (∀y:`BOOK`(y)) (∃x:`BOY`(x)) `READ`(x, y) **or** (∃x:`BOY`(x)) (∀y:`BOOK`(y)) `READ`(x, y). Any time you have any two Operators (quantifiers, negatives, modals) in a clause, you're going to generate ambiguities, and idiomatic syntax to accomodate them.

Comment: I see. I thought there are some rules regarding this because the sentence "everyday someone sleeps" isn't as ambiguous despite being almost same.

Comment: That's because it's silly. Everybody does sleep every day, more or less, and sleeping is not a segmentable activity (i.e, you can't have 8 people get a night's sleep in one hour). If you want to see prototype phenomena, don't muddy the examples up with irrelevant details.

Comment: But, using your example, doesn't "Every book, some boy reads it" also sound less ambiguous than the original? I don't think it's entirely because of the silliness of examples.

Comment: As I said, when you have two Operators in a sentence, you come across a lot of idiomatic syntax to accomodate them. [Left-Dislocation (which is the syntactic rule that produces that sentence)](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf) is one example.

Comment: I see, that answers my question.

Comment: There are some sentences that are correctable because we can at least see what the intended meaning was. But this is one case where I can make no suggestion, because I have no idea of the intended meaning. Is it your own sentence, or are you quoting from some other source?

Comment: My own sentence. I am purely interested in prototype phenomena according the title of the question and not that particular sentence.

Comment: A well-known joke ran: "A man is knocked down every five minutes on Britain's roads. And he's getting really fed up about it."

Comment: Actually, neither interpretation is possible, because the adverb would be *every day*. The *everyday* you have in there is an adjective, and the sentence plain does not parse.

Answer (score 1):

As John Lawler notes in the comments:

> Aside from being a silly sentence, it's an ambiguous one, a classic Quantifier Ambiguity,
>   an adverbial version of *Some boy read every book*, which is either
>
> - (∀y:`BOOK`(y)) (∃x:`BOY`(x)) `READ`(x, y) "For every book Y there is a boy X, such that X read Y"
>     **or**
> - (∃x:`BOY`(x)) (∀y:`BOOK`(y)) `READ`(x, y). "There is a boy X such that for every book Y,  X read Y"
>
> Any time you have any two Operators (quantifiers, negatives, modals) in a clause, you're going to generate ambiguities, and idiomatic syntax to accomodate them.

Answer (score 1):

**BOTH!**

Say we have two groups of people (group A and group B) each containing 100 people.

In group A there is one person who sleeps every day.  The other 99 people sleep occasionally.

In group B no person sleeps every day, but every day at least one person sleeps.

The statement would be true for both groups.